# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context in linq

Tags: c#, linq

These are my queries:

```
var originals = (from x in db1.MyStrings select x).ToList();

var translations = (from x in db2.MyTranslations.Where(x => x.language_id == languageId)
                                join y in originals
                                on x.original_id equals y.Id into joined
                                from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                select new { x.language_id, x.translation, j.Content, j.Id }).ToList();
```

I have two tables in 2 different databases. I want to get all of the original strings  and join them with their translations, if there are any. So the list wil be the same size with the original strings table in db1. MyStrings stores the original strings, MyTransaltions stores the translations.

The error I get now is: Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyString'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Is MyStrings a table or some raw data ?

Comment: @dotnetstep MyStrings has 2 columns: id and content, they are int and nvarchar.

Comment: You are joining the db on an in-memory list. Remove the `.ToList()` in the first statement.

Comment: @Silvermind If I remove the .ToList() command I get an error saying  that there are 2 different db contexts.

Comment: Ok, but there is your problem. You cannot join a datacontext on an in-memory list. If you have to mix datacontexts than that is the direction you need to go. Another option is to keep the `.ToList()` and put the 'unjoined' results of the table from db2 in a list and join in-memory. But that can be a bad way if the results are big and the frequency of this call is often.

Answer (score 0):

Just try if following is work and If problem is same I faced once.

```
var translations = (from y in originals 
                                join x in db2.MyTranslations.Where(x => x.language_id == languageId)
                                on x.original_id equals y.Id into joined
                                from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                select new { x.language_id, x.translation, j.Content, j.Id }).ToList();
```